# Windows - auto launch specific applications on boot

Tags: windows, node.js, executable, boot

Developing a kiosk application in Windows OS. When the machine boots up 3 things have to happen in sequence

1. a node.js server launches
2. the browser containing the web app launches in kiosk mode
3. another client application launches

Is there a utlility that easilly accomplishes this, or is there an easy way to do this in the command-line? I'm guessing some type of BSCH script could also be use but I'm not a BSCH expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a script in any language you want to automate this  (even using nodejs) and then just install a shortcut to that script in the user's `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder.

Comment: Won't this start the application or execute the script when the user logs in? I think the question is looking for a method where the application or scrip are started when the computer starts, no user log in requiered.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, the folder is `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.