# auto start node.js server on boot in Windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows

Running a node.js server in Windows. I need the server to auto launch on startup-boot, followed by launching a standalone application. can anyone tell me the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20724855

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [run node as a Windows Service](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows).  Services start right after boot, before login.

As far as launching the standalone app, the answer depends on what it is.  If it's a GUI app, you'll need to configure Windows to [automatically log in](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+auto+login), then you can just put it in the Startup folder.  If it doesn't have a GUI, you can just use `child_process` to spawn the app from node.