# how to run windows service automatically using nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, windows, service

Is it possible to run node application automatically?

For example: once I turn on the machine it will run automatically.

Notes: Cross-Platform solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445599/auto-start-node-js-server-on-boot - This should help you