# How to host a React App on Standalone Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, hosting, host

I have a stand alone server that will only be connected to a lan without outside internet access.  I am new to hosting so I am lost as to what to use and how to do it.

I have run my react app using npm start. But how do I configure node to start up a react app when the stand alone server starts?

Is there some other windows based host that is easier to configure to run a React app?

Comment: Depends on OS, if you are using linux you can create a service which auto starts on system bootup, and you can write a bash script which has command to start your app. Service file will use that bash script file to start app.

Comment: Actually service restarts if anything went wrong, if somehow your server is down, you can set a time when service will restart.

Comment: PM2 is what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661027/1207930

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a Linux server distribution to achieve this. Quite easy actually but not sure how to do that on a Windows machine, unfortunately. You can simply Google for "How To Setup A Web Server And Host Website" I am sure there are a lot of guides and tutorials